# How do I skip a match when using Ctrl+D for multiple selections in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I have some code like:

```
testVar = { a: 1 };
testVariable1 = 2;
var c = testVar.a + testVariable2;
var d = testVar;
```

I want to rename "testVar" variable. When I set multiple cursors with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and edit variable, "testVariable" is also selected and edited.

Is there a way to skip some selections while setting multiple cursors with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?

Comment: This applies to VS Code as well, which purposely tried to mimic Sublime behavior for multiple cursors.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

(for OS X: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

Needs a bit of practice, but gets the job done!

Comment: @Qwerty: Alt+F3 Selects all occurrences.

Comment: @Romain wrote "Needs a bit of practice". I think what that means is that it could be more intuitive. Don't press the key combo until what you want to skip is highlighted. E.g. if you have 3 matches, and you want to skip the 2nd, first highlight the 1st, press CTRL+D to highlight the 2nd, THEN press the key combo to skip the 2nd match and highlight the 3rd. Help?

Comment: Add this to user keymap and shorten the practice time to nearly 0! `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"], "command": "find_under_expand_skip" }`

Comment: Updated answer, in keybindings,json add this line:
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "editor.action.moveSelectionToNextFindMatch",
    "when": "editorFocus"
  },

Answer (score 99):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the same time to skip a selection. If you went too far with your selection, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to return to a previous selection.

*Note*: Replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> for Mac OS X.

The default configuration for this can be viewed by going to `Preferences` > `Key Bindings-Default` in the application menubar, where you will see something like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand_skip" }
```

If you want, you can configure the keys as per your needs, by going to `Preferences` > `Key Bindings-User` and copy the above code and then change the keys.

Answer (score 66):

If you have the cursor over the word and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to select the word. The next time you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> it should select the next highlighted word.

If you double click to select word, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will select the exact string not just the highlighted ones.

In other words, **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> with nothing highlighted does whole-word search**. If you have something highlighted already, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will do substring searching.

I have tested and it works in Sublime Text 2 Version 2.0.1, Build 2217.

Comment: This is actually the only true solution to this problem. People are upvoting brainlessly.

Comment: `ctrl`+`D` **with nothing selected** is **Case sensitive** too.

Comment: @vankatvb I'm not finding that to be true... `Ctrl`+`D` with nothing selected is still case-insensitive to me. It'll outline only case-sensitive matches, but actually using the shortcut or `Alt`+`F3` will select those that don't match case.

Comment: Btw here's the same answer in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18422707/782045

Comment: @Qwerty it is not the "only true solution", it is as much of a solution as `ctrl-k ctrl-d`. Both have their use case. This answer, for example, is not useful when the search string is not surrounded by whitespace. Randomly calling people brainless is not very helpful either.

Comment: @phil294 Back in the day I was a different person. I wish I could change the comment now.

Answer (score 13):

Place curser **before** the variable, do not select the variable, hit <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to select every occurence of the variable, not pattern.

Answer (score 12):

Updated answer for vscode in 2020 on windows, in keybindings.json add this line to skip the next selected occurrence easily:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "command": "editor.action.moveSelectionToNextFindMatch",
    "when": "editorFocus"
  },
```

*yes I know the question is for sublime text, but I found it by googling the same question + vscode, so it might help someone since the mappings are identical.

Answer (score 3):

I think I get why it was confusing to me: This is not skipping, it's *unselecting*.

You hit `Ctrl+D` as usual and if you select one by mistake you do `Ctrl+K, D` where you first press the `K` and then the `D` without letting go the `Ctrl`. This unselects the selection.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was using ctrl+D to add a new selection
and ctrl+U to remove the last selection
Hope it helped